# Doing PCA with varimax rotation in R

Tags: r, pca

My code has gone south.

I'm importing a data 578x17 sheet from csv using the:

```
Data=read.csv("Data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=',', dec='.', row.names= 1 , stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

My correlations and covariance matrices are the same.

When I try to do a PCA and a PCA with a Varimax Rotation, I get the same results:

```
PCA=princomp(x = Data, cor = TRUE, scores = TRUE)
Varimax<-princomp(Data, rotation="varimax")
```

When I try to do a Varimax rotation in a different way, I get:

```
varimax<-varimax(PCA$rotation[,1:5])
```

> Error in if (nc < 2) return(x) : argument is of length zero

I'm not sure whether the problem is my code, or my .csv file, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Voting to close because it is code-specific. If one removes code lines then it becomes totally unclear what the speech is about.

Comment: I am not familiar with R and so am not sure why you get the error message, but there are many things wrong here. First, `princomp` does not accept `rotation` argument, so it's probably ignored and that's why (probably) you get the "same result"; in other words, you are not doing PCA+varimax this way. Second, varimax rotation is supposed to be done on *loadings* not on eigenvectors and `PCA$rotation` are eigenvectors. So if you want to run `varimax` manually you should do it differently. See my answer in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59213.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compute varimax-rotated principal components in R?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59213/how-to-compute-varimax-rotated-principal-components-in-r)

Comment: Thanks! I figured out my code problems. Much appreciated!

Comment: Post the solution you found @Matt

Answer (score 0):

### varimax rotation in PCA with vegan's rda()

### The basics of this answer has been taken from:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59213/how-to-compute-varimax-rotated-principal-components-in-r

### suppose that the data matrix name is mydata

```
library(vegan)
library(pracma)
pca.env = rda(mydata, scale=T)
loading = scores(pca.env, choices=c(1,2))$species    #choices determines which pc to be taken
rloading = varimax(loading)$loadings
iloading = t(pinv(rloading))
scores = scale(mydata) %*% iloading
```

## biplot

```
r = range(c(rloading, scores))
plot(scores, xlim = r, ylim= r, xlab= "PC1 ", ylab= "PC2 ")
arrows(0,0, rloading[,1], rloading[,2], length=0.1, col=2)
text(rloading[,1], rloading[,2], labels = colnames(mydata), pos=3, col=2)
text(scores[,1], scores[,2], labels = rownames(mydata), pos = 3)
abline(h=0, lty=3)
abline(v=0, lty=3)
```